# Unable to install guest additions in Kali 2018

Tags: linux, virtualbox, kali-linux, headers

I've installed Kali 2018 in VirtualBox on a Windows 10 Host.
Attempted to install guest additions, following instructions in Kali doc.
https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-virtual-box-guest

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y virtualbox-guest-x11
reboot
```

**copied to root directory and edited permissions as follows...**

```
cp /media/cd-rom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run /root/
chmod 755 /root/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

**executed file...**

```
root@kali2018:~# ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing VirtualBox 5.2.18 Guest Additions for Linux........
VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
Removing installed version 5.2.18 of VirtualBox Guest Additions...
Copying additional installer modules ...
Installing additional modules ...
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Building the VirtualBox Guest Additions kernel modules.  This may take a while.
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
for adding new hardware support to the system.
The distribution packages containing the headers are probably:
    linux-headers-amd64 linux-headers-4.17.0-kali1-amd64
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Running kernel modules will not be replaced until the system is restarted
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Starting.
VirtualBox Guest Additions: modprobe vboxsf failed
```

**checked kernel and header cache**

```
root@kali2018:~# uname -r
4.17.0-kali1-amd64
```

```
root@kali2018:~# apt-cache search linux-headers
aufs-dkms - DKMS files to build and install aufs
linux-headers-4.18.0-kali2-all - All header files for Linux 4.18 (meta-package)
linux-headers-4.18.0-kali2-all-amd64 - All header files for Linux 4.18 (meta-package)
linux-headers-4.18.0-kali2-amd64 - Header files for Linux 4.18.0-kali2-amd64
linux-headers-4.18.0-kali2-cloud-amd64 - Header files for Linux 4.18.0-kali2-cloud-amd64
linux-headers-4.18.0-kali2-common - Common header files for Linux 4.18.0-kali2
linux-headers-4.18.0-kali2-common-rt - Common header files for Linux 4.18.0-kali2-rt
linux-headers-4.18.0-kali2-rt-amd64 - Header files for Linux 4.18.0-kali2-rt-amd64
linux-headers-amd64 - Header files for Linux amd64 configuration (meta-package)
linux-headers-cloud-amd64 - Header files for Linux cloud-amd64 configuration (meta-package)
linux-headers-rt-amd64 - Header files for Linux rt-amd64 configuration (meta-package)
linux-libc-dev-alpha-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-amd64-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-arm64-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-armel-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-armhf-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-hppa-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-i386-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-m68k-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mips-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mips64-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mips64el-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mips64r6-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mips64r6el-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mipsel-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mipsn32-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mipsn32el-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mipsn32r6-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mipsn32r6el-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mipsr6-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-mipsr6el-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-powerpc-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-powerpcspe-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-ppc64-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-ppc64el-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-riscv64-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-s390x-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-sh4-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-sparc64-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-x32-cross - Linux Kernel Headers for development (for cross-compiling)
```

**so the package i need doesn't appear to be available? I tried this as well...**

```
root@kali2018:~# apt-get install linux-headers-4.17.0-kali1-amd64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.17.0-kali1-amd64
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.17.0-kali1-amd64'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.17.0-kali1-amd64'
```

**How do I install the appropriate headers?**

Comment: facing the same issue here as well, did you mange to get a fix for this ?

Comment: No. I haven't messed with it in a while.

Comment: alright, I just use vmware instead :)